# Swipe method not supporting in android appium

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I tried with swipe method in android,but it not working.

Code:-

```
public void swipe() {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    HashMap < String, Double > swipeObject = new HashMap < String, Double > ();
    swipeObject.put("startX", 0.95);
    swipeObject.put("startY", 0.5);
    swipeObject.put("endX", 0.05);
    swipeObject.put("endY", 0.5);
    swipeObject.put("duration", 1.0);
    js.executeScript("emulator: swipe", swipeObject);
}
```

**Error:-**

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented.
```

Any help great apprciation.

Comment: Did you try driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, duration); ?

Comment: yes tried ,but same problem occured.

Comment: For me swipe method is working...Can you please share screenshot of your screen bound values because I have faces same issue in past because of incorrect co-ordinate passed. Also make sure you have imported java.client latest JARS to your project.

Comment: I have called swipe() with above co ordinates but still problem replicated.

Comment: Did you integrate client JAR files to your project?

Comment: then swipe must work..Please share you screen with bound values where you want to swipe.

Comment: I am using appium version 1.3.4

Comment: Its ok , I think only co-ordinate look incorrect.

Comment: Are you using the latest java client?

Comment: yes using latest one

Answer (score 2):

Changing the context to `NATIVE_APP` worked for me:

```
String originalContext = driver.getContext();
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, duration);
driver.context(originalContext );
```

Answer (score 1):

Swipe is not implemented /supported on web views , check the context and change it to Native before doing a swipe , you can revert to Web View after the swipe .

Comment: For me it works -  as you said we need to switch to Native context before swipe, but hardcoding x, y is not the best way. I have tried to get coordinates of element I want to swap:  int startx = msg.getLocation().getX();  int starty = msg.getLocation().getY(); but it returns coordinates which are not absolute but relative to the browser view

Answer (score 0):

Check your coordinates once and take coordinates from appium inspector if u have access to mac.

And minimum value of time should be 500 in order for swipe to work, can you post your complete log ?